# Django Autocomplete-Light allow any text input fields

Tags: django-crispy-forms, django-autocomplete-light

I have Django ***Autocomplete-light*** running with ***Crispy Forms***, but I need to allow users to enter **any** text into the form. At the moment the user can either select one of the options from the autocomplete dropdown, or nothing.

Note that I am using the Select2ListView from Autocomplete-light

Does anyone know how I can easily modify Autocomplete-light, or Crispy Forms to allow any text to be entered?

Thanks
Stephen

Answer (score 0):

Your field is linked to a `foreignkey`, so you can create an inline form that points to your related `model` in your view.